# ctypes: accessing members of a structure from its pointer

Tags: ctypes

I am trying to access a c++ function from python with following definition:

```c
int PEQueryJob(void *Handle, char *jobId, JobResults **results) {

     // Allocate Memory to results structure and fill its members
}
```

Python code:

```python
class JobProgress(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('JobStatus', c_int),
                ('queueTime', c_uint32),
                ('analyseTime', c_uint32),
                ('itemCount', c_uint32),
                ('completeTime', c_uint32),]

class JobResults(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('JobProgress', JobProgress),
                ('modifiedDataCreated', c_uint32),
                ('scanResult', c_char_p),
                ('scanLength',  c_uint64),
                ('metadataLength', c_uint32),
                ('metadata', MetadataItem),
                ('modifiedData', c_char_p),
                ('modifiedDataLength', c_uint64),]

queryjob = lib.PEQueryJob
job_results = POINTER(JobResults)()
queryjob(Handle, submitjob_jobid, byref(job_results))
```

C definitions:

```c
typedef enum JobStatus {
    QUEUED = 0,          
    IN_PROGRESS,        
    COMPLETE,            
    FAILED,             
    REMOVED
} JobStatus;

typedef struct _MswJobProgress {
    JobStatus   status;        
    Uint32      queueTime;     
    Uint32      analyseTime;   
    Uint32      itemCount;     
    Uint32      completeTime;
} Jobprogress;

typedef struct JobResults {
    JobProgress progress;               
    Uint32      modifiedDataCreated;    
    char *      scanResult;         
    Uint64      scanLength;             
    Uint32      metadataLength;     
    Item**      metadata;               
    char *      modifiedData;         
    Uint64      modifiedDataLength;
} JobResults;
```

1. Please let me know the correct way of passing the arguments just in case if there is any issue
2. How do i Access the members of job_results structure which was filled by C++ code??

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#pointers

Comment: FYI, `job_results` is a `JobResults *`, not a `JobResults **`, so the title of your question makes no sense.

Comment: hi eryksun, the c++ function is expecting a double pointer to JobResults can you please let me know if the way i have passed the args is wrong

Comment: No, it's right, i.e. `byref(job_results)` is a `JobResults **`. You're passing the address of your `job_results` pointer for the C function to update the address stored in it. Then you can dereference `job_results` as described in the above link, i.e. `job_results[0]` or `job_results.contents`.

Comment: i tried accessing job_results[0]. scanResult but i always end up getting a None even though the c++ code has filled it correctly

Comment: `job_results[0].scanResult` is correct. The 0 means to get the `JobResults` value at offset 0 from the address. If it was actually a `JobResults` array you could get a different array element, but in this case it's not an array, so only the 0th element is valid. If the `scanResult` field is `None`, then the function stored a `NULL` `char *`pointer there, or you've defined the structure incorrectly.

Comment: Ok Let me add the C++ struct def for your reference  so that you can correct me if any of my definitions are wrong

Comment: Sorry that was just a copy paste mistake it is indeed a JobProgress will correct it

Comment: What's the value of `job_results[0].scanLength`?

Comment: It is coming as 0 Then i think value of scanResult is justified ...then atleast from my understanding there is no issue with code might be a c++ api issue not setting it correctly what do you think??